# Copy and paste keeps positive semi-definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive semi-definite matrix. We can show that
$$\bar{S} \triangleq\begin{pmatrix}
S & S \\ 
S & S
\end{pmatrix}$$
is positive semi-definite as well. To show this algebraically, considering the decomposition of $S = V^2$ with $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
S & S \\ 
S & S
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
V & V \\ 
V & V
\end{pmatrix}^2.
$$
Although I derived the algebraic proof, I still haven't fully understood it yet.
I wonder if there is any simple and direct interpretation that just demonstrates that $\bar S$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin: Thanks for pointing it out! I have corrected this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $S$ is positive definite. Consider $\bar Sz\cdot z$ for any $z\in\Bbb R^{2n}$. Write $z=(x,y)\in\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$. Since $S$ is positive definite, $Sv\cdot v\ge 0$ for all $v$, with equality holding only for $v=0$. Thus, we have
$$\bar Sz\cdot z = S(x+y)\cdot (x+y) \ge 0,$$
with equality holding iff $x=-y$. Thus, $\bar S$ is positive semidefinite. (If $S$ is only semidefinite, we still have the inequality here, but equality may hold for $x+y\ne 0$.)